# Allowing users to edit or delete list of uploaded files on Flask before submitting

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

Currently building a Flask app and using wtforms to help with building a file upload field, but I would like **users to have the option to view the (multiple) file names they have already uploaded, either add more files, or remove some files that might have been wrongly uploaded**, before finally clicking submit and the final list of files are then processed. Would prefer to continue using wtforms but open to any other solutions.

Minimum example: App.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, MultipleFileField, SubmitField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'example'


class exampleUpload(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('name')
    input_files = MultipleFileField('files')
    submit = SubmitField('submit')



@app.route('/')
def index():
    form = exampleUpload()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # allow user to freely add, remove, make sure that uploaded files are correct before
        # pressing the submit button
        if form.submit.data:
            files = form.input_files.data
            # do_something(files)
        return '<h1> Done'
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{ form.name }}
    {{ form.input_files }}
    <hr>
    {{ form.submit }}
</body>
</html>
```